# docker-compose up fails with " Unable to find a node that satisfies the following conditions "

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

My `docker-compose.yml` is:

```
version: '2'

services:

  db:
    build: ./postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/data
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - "constraint:node=edge"
    networks:
      - back-tier

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  back-tier:
    driver: overlay
```

And I have two nodes in a `docker swarm` in `google`. I created them with the following:

```
## Swarm master
docker-machine --debug create --driver google --google-project my_project --swarm --swarm-discovery="consul://$cip:8500" --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$cip:8500" --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth0:2376" --swarm-master --engine-label node=director --google-disk-size 100 --google-machine-type n1-standard-2 director

## Nodo edge
docker-machine --debug create --driver google --google-project my_project --swarm --swarm-discovery="consul://$cip:8500" --engine-opt="cluster-store=consul://$cip:8500" --engine-opt="cluster-advertise=eth0:2376" --engine-label node=edge --google-scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write --google-disk-size 250 --google-machine-type n1-standard-4 node-0
```

And I can see both of them with `docker-machine ls`

```
consul            -           google      Running   tcp://X.X.X.X:2376                       v1.11.0   
director          * (swarm)   google      Running   tcp://X.X.X.X:2376   director (master)   v1.11.0   
node-0            -           google      Running   tcp://X.X.X.X:2376    director            v1.11.0
```

And the `labels` worked:

```
$ docker-machine ls --filter label=node=edge            
NAME     ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE     URL                        SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
node-0   -        google   Running   tcp://X.X.X.X:2376           v1.11.0
```

The `docker info` output is

```
$ docker info
Containers: 3
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 4
Server Version: swarm/1.2.0
Role: primary
Strategy: spread
Filters: health, port, dependency, affinity, constraint
Nodes: 2
 director: 104.154.88.186:2376
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 2
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 2
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 7.67 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=4.2.0-18-generic, node=director, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 15.10, provider=google, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-04-24T04:43:50Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.0
 node-0: 104.197.85.59:2376
  └ Status: Healthy
  └ Containers: 1
  └ Reserved CPUs: 0 / 4
  └ Reserved Memory: 0 B / 15.42 GiB
  └ Labels: executiondriver=, kernelversion=4.2.0-18-generic, node=edge, operatingsystem=Ubuntu 15.10, provider=google, storagedriver=aufs
  └ Error: (none)
  └ UpdatedAt: 2016-04-24T04:43:41Z
  └ ServerVersion: 1.11.0
Plugins: 
 Volume: 
 Network: 
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-18-generic
Operating System: linux
Architecture: amd64
CPUs: 6
Total Memory: 23.09 GiB
Name: director
Docker Root Dir: 
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
```

So everything seems right, right?

But when I try to run `docker-compose up -d`

The following happens:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "infraestructura_back-tier" with driver "overlay"
Creating volume "infraestructura_postgres-data" with local driver
Building db
Step 1 : FROM postgres:9.5
 ---> 0f3af79d8673
Step 2 : ADD create_tables.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2f818eec1228
Successfully built 2f818eec1228
WARNING: Image for service db was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating infraestructura_db_1

ERROR: for db  Unable to find a node that satisfies the following conditions 
[port 5432 (Bridge mode)]
```

This is happenning not matter what I do (trying another image, destroying and recreating the nodes, etc.) , except removing the `"constraint:node=edge"`

What I am doing wrong?

BTW, my versions are:

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.0
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   4dc5990
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 18:38:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      swarm/1.2.0
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   a6c1f14
 Built:        Wed Apr 13 05:58:31 UTC 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64


$ docker-machine -v
docker-machine version 0.6.0, build e27fb87


$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.7.0, build 0d7bf73


$ docker run --rm swarm -version
swarm version 1.2.0 (a6c1f14)
```

Comment: As your `docker info` says there are 3 running containers I'd guess there is already a running postgres container on that node. What does `docker ps` look like?

Comment: `docker ps` returns empty, the 3 containers are the `swarm-agent` containers

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same error

Answer (score 2):

You may try to change this line:

```
- "constraint:node=edge"
```

to

```
- "constraint:node==edge"
```

Answer (score 1):

The error mentions port `5432`.

```
ERROR: for db  Unable to find a node that satisfies the following conditions 
[port 5432 (Bridge mode)]
```

So Docker fails after checking if there is a node with port 5432 open.
Are you sure that Postgres isn't already running on both nodes or some other container is already listening on port 5432?

Answer (score 1):

Can you destroy the old containers with docker-compose rm before creating the new ones.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).